# Получение объекта

Tags: javascript

Пишу приложение с использованием вебсокетов.
Есть объект от модели:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
   start: function() {
       this.ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/gameplay");
       this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
   },
   onMessage: function() {
       console.log('example');
       //this.anotherFunc();
   },
   anotherFunc() {
       //...
   }
});
```

Проблема в том, что метод onMessage() вызывается у сокета и в нем я уже не имею доступа к членам модели. Как можно обойти это, не делая модель глобальным объектом?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
```